# How do I disable the touchpad (Windows 7) on my Dell E6400 - before I go nuts?

Tags: touchpad, dell-latitude

I use a USB mouse but the touchpad will not switch off using Fn/F5 like it ought to. At the moment I have sticky tape on it, but it still throws the cursor around.

Comment: Your operating system might make a difference.

Comment: @Scott   Ermm, yes. Good Point. (edited).

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7 (and later versions?) <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
brings up the Windows Mobility Center,
which includes a button for enabling/disabling the touchpad. 
And, on my Dell Inspiron,
“Control Panel” → “Mouse” gives access to finer-grained controls.